# rotateArray using tmp

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int rotateArray(int arr[], int size);

int main()
{
    int size,i,arr[i];

    printf("Enter N: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",rotateArray(arr[i],size));
    }

}

int rotateArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    int i, tmp;
    tmp = arr[0];
    for(i=1;i<size;i++)
    {
        arr[i-1] = arr[i];
        arr[size-1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

I'm confused as to what I did wrong here.. I'm sorry if I missed something.
[image]

The question need me to use this given function to make rotateArray
and the right picture is the result it supposed to be but my result is just empty space

Edited : I have also tried this after the scanf of array

```
int rotateArray(arr,size);

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
```

but still ended up with the blank space

Edited 2: I'm not sure on how to do void rotateArray(...) yet so I started with int rotateArray(...)

Edit 3 :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int size,i,arr[i];
    printf("Enter N: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
rotateArray(arr,size);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }

}

void rotateArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    int i, tmp;
    tmp = arr[0];
    for(i=1;i<size;i++)
    {
        arr[i-1] = arr[i];
    }
        arr[size-1] = tmp;

}
```

This is the final code I got which work if I declared i = 10
but the thing I'm confused about this is that if I put i = 2 then when I Enter size as 10 it wouldn't work

Edited ( Final )

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int size,i;
    printf("Enter N: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    int arr[size];
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
rotateArray(arr,size);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }

}

void rotateArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    int i, tmp;
    tmp = arr[0];
    for(i=1;i<size;i++)
    {
        arr[i-1] = arr[i];
    }
        arr[size-1] = tmp;

}
```

this is the last edit and I have changed int arr[size]; to be after the scanf which make this work

Thanks to all the people who have answered !

Comment: `arr[size-1] = tmp;` should be after the for loop

Comment: You have changed the function type from `void` to `int` but you have not returned anything. Check out all compiler warnings. Change it to `void` and just call it outside the loop with `rotateArray(arr, size);` and then in the loop print with `printf("%d ", arr[i],size);`

Comment: change the `int` to `void` and also add this loop for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    } 
in the end

Comment: Thank you! I have fixed all the mistake but unfortunately the problem is still the same.

Comment: Simply put, the problem lies in the fact that the entry you try to print is the return-value of rotateArray. It doesn't return anything, so you end up printing what happens to be 0. You should only call rotateArray once, right after the scanf loop. then you should print `arr[i]` instead of `rotateArray(arr[i])`. As someone else mentioned, you should put the tmp var back into the array *outside* the loop and finally, in the main func, you should give `arr` an actual size when you declare it. Hint: What does `i` hold at that point, when it hasn't been initialized yet?

Comment: I am totally confused on the question? The picture included in the question shows valid code to rotate the array left by `1`. What part of that code are you confused by? Granted the code omits the `{ ... }` guards on the `for` loop, but that is apparent from context.

Comment: he is getting this error  `expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
    3 | int rotateArray(int arr[], int size);`

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks you so much ! I have fixed this by giving  int i = 10;  
Edited : but I'm not sure on why if I give i = 0 or i = 2 it won't work
but i = 10 and input size = 12  does work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that produces your output. I'm using a static array for the data, you'll either want to (0) give it and the user input a pre-determined maximum length or (1) allocate some memory for the array after getting the size from the user.

To avoid the classic mistake of a `,` after the last entry in a printed list, we simply put it before all entries except the first.

CPUs I've used have both have a rotate-left and a rotate-right instruction. While they operate on bits and we use integers, it's exactly the same process, albeit with different sized chunks of data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void rotateArrayLeft(int data[], int nElems)
{
    int tmp = data[0];
    for (int i=0; i<nElems-1; i++)
    {
        data[i] = data[i+1];
    }
    data[nElems-1] = tmp;
}

void rotateArrayRight(int data[], int nElems)
{
    int tmp = data[nElems-1];
    for (int i=nElems-1; i>0; i--)
    {
        data[i] = data[i-1];
    }
    data[0] = tmp;
}

void showArray(int data[], int nElems)
{
    for (int i=0; i<nElems; i++)
    {
        if (i!=0)
            printf(", ");
        printf("%d", data[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {3,4,1,9,5,33,2,90,11,6};
    int nElems = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    printf("Initial Array\n");
    showArray(arr, nElems);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Rotated Left Array\n");
    rotateArrayLeft(arr, nElems);
    showArray(arr, nElems);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Rotated Right Array\n");
    rotateArrayRight(arr, nElems);
    showArray(arr, nElems);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```c
for(i = 1; i < size; i++)
    arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
arr[size - 1] = tmp;
```

is the eqivalent of:

```c
for(i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
    arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
}
arr[size - 1] = tmp;
```

not:

```c
for(i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
    arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
    arr[size - 1] = tmp;
}
```

Another thing is you didn't return anything in `rotateArray()`, although you defined the return type as an `int`. Change the return type to `void`.

Also, you:

```c
int i;
int arr[i]
```

You have only declared `i`, not assigned it a value. And you make `i` the size of `arr`, which leads to undefined behavior.

You should:

```c
scanf("%d",&size); // assigned a value to size
int arr[size] // create arr with size (size)
```

Comment: Thanks ! but even tho I have changed it's still not working.

Comment: @WWoPPoWW what is not working exactly? Can you tell me what is the output and expected output?

Comment: The expected output is in the right picture but the output I got is none. Like.. nothing appear at all after I put in all the number. The only thing appeared is "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005) .............................. "

Comment: @WWoPPoWW I have spotted the error. Please wait a few minutes.